# Unix Epoch Timestamp to Human readable Date time and back conversions

Tags: linux, date, unix, datetime, erlang

In Erlang, i can get the Unix Epoc Timestamp by the code below:

```
{MegaSecs, Secs, MicroSecs} = now().
UnixTime = MegaSecs * 1000000 + Secs.
```

OR (as suggested by some sites)

```
calendar:datetime_to_gregorian_seconds(calendar:universal_time())-719528*24*3600.
```

However that conversion has occured for the result of `erlang:now()`. What if i have a given date time value in the format: `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS"` e.g. `"2012-12-30 15:13:40"` 
The time being in 24 hour format.
 This [website gives the complete picture](http://www.epochconverter.com/) of what i need to be able to do in erlang.
How can i interchangeably convert from human readable formats to unix epoch timestamps and vice versa "at will", in my code. Such that if in my programs i store the timestamps as Unix Epochs, at the time of reading them, i can retrieve the human readable format automatically from the unix timestamp value or viceversa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as tempo there's qdate:

https://github.com/choptastic/qdate

Would be interested to hear comparisons :)

Comment: +1 well documented, comfortable to use and absolutely beautiful. Thank you so much for this. Exactly covers all that i ever needed to do with time management.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this lib: https://github.com/selectel/tempo

> *tempo* is a library for parsing and formatting dates in Erlang. It provides a clean and nice interface to libc's strptime and strftime functions, which are unfortunately missing from Erlang's standard library.